# Adding a vertical line and highlighting a value in y axis label in graph using plotly R?

Tags: r, plotly

This is my code:

```
Name<-c('Launch', 'Login', 'Default_Salary_Page', 'DownloadSlip', 'Advance_SalaryPage', 'Raise', 'Certificates')
Avg<-c(2.35,8.91,5.06,1.2,4.22,7.42,1.00)
Percentile_90<-c(3.35,9.91,6.06,2.54,6.45,8.12,2.05)
input<-data.frame(Name,Avg,Percentile_90
plot_ly(input,x=~Name,y=~Avg,name='Avg', type='scatter')%>%add_trace(y=~Percentile_90,name='Percentile_90', type='scatter')
```

I got a nice plot but I want to add some extra features in the plot. I want to add a red vertical line in y axis at value 5 and name that line as SLA.

Can somebody suggest any solution.

Comment: Try editing this post with appropriate returns and tabs, using the  curly brackets around the code so it is readable as cpde. You will find help quicker if people are sure they know what it says.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
p <- plot_ly(input, x=~Name, y=~Avg, name='Avg', mode='markers', type='scatter')
p <- add_trace(p, y=~Percentile_90, name='Percentile_90', mode='markers', type='scatter')
p <- add_lines(p, y = 5,name='SLA', mode='lines', line=list(color='red'))
p
```

Comment: Thanks @guscht. Your code somehow gave me an idea but it was still having some issues with my expected result. I modified ur code and now getting the perfect result..

Comment: add_lines(p, y = 5,name="SLA",color="red", list(color = 'rgb(205, 12, 24)', width = 4, dash = 'dot'))